# How to read strings in Perl as correct form from text file

Tags: string, perl, file

I want to read text from ".txt" file in correct form in perl,

I have the following text in ".txt" file:

> Feste begründen die Identität einer Gemeinschaft und ihr
>   Selbstverständnis nach innen. Eng damit verbunden sind Emotionen, die
>   zunächst im Zusammenhang mit einer gefühlten Zugehörigkeit zu einer
>   Fest-Gemeinschaft zu verstehen sind. Mit jedem Fest verbindet sich
>   aber auch eine emotionale Überschreitung des Alltags: Der bestimmende
>   festliche Eindruck – die feierliche Gestimmtheit – ist der einer
>   erhöhten Bedeutungshaftigkeit des Lebens, durch die sich das Festliche
>   aus dem Lauf des Alltagslebens hervorhebt und dessen Wirkmächtigkeit
>   zuvörderst anhand der Analyse des bürgerlichen Geburtstages sinnfällig
>   demonstriert werden soll.

I can read the .txt file with ease but I can not read in correct form, I mean when I read from text file in perl i get the above string as :

[image]

Kindly give your ideas to solve this,

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You likely are opening the file with the wrong encoding.  Take a look at [`PerlIO`](http://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html).

```
open(my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", "data.utf") or die "Can't open data.utf: $!";
my @in = <$fh>;
close($fh);
```

Comment: Thanks Miller, now I can read the text but there is some unformatted text present.

eg:

`Feste begründen die Identität einer Gemeinschaft und ihr Selbstverständnis nach innen. Eng damit verbunden sind Emotionen, die zunächst im Zusammenhang mit einer gefühlten`

this lines are not converted correctly if you want screeshot means I can send

Comment: The output channel also have to have the correct encoding. So if you print on the console you need to call 
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
before you print.

Comment: @user3354853 I believe szabgab has already given you the other answer.  However, if you want to give an update to your problem, just edit your original question to add the new information and issues.

Comment: I followed szabgab procedure before reading the content from text file but I still can not read correctly, I still can get the same unformatted text as shown above in my previous comment to you, Mr.Miller, I'm sorry I m new to perl, so please apologize if I didnt understand your reply

Comment: @user3354853: it isn't at all clear what is wrong with the text you are seeing now. It looks identical to the input to me. Please describe the error that you are seeing